# How many different tasty cakes can be made?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

We have a $3 \times 3$ board and $10$ units of different ingredients ($3$ Sweets, $3$ Fruits, $3$ Salted, $1$ Cookie), to make a cake.

A $9$-ingredient cake is considered tasty when three same ingredients are aligned vertically or horizontally on the board. Cookie is special, it can be aligned with any ingredient.

Calculate the maximum number of different tasty cakes that can be made.

My result is $6444$, but is wrong..

Comment: Welcome to math. SE.   Please show your attempt and exactly where you need help

Comment: well, i made an algorithim that try every combination possible and that give me 6444 combinations possible ... but the site where I have to enter the result says is wrong

Comment: Do you count symetries?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon what do you mean symetries? can you give me an example?

Comment: Well sweets fruits salted is the same cake as salted fruits sweet. It's just rotated 180 degrees.

Comment: well, in my 6444 the symetries are counted like diferents... if not the result will be 3222?

Comment: It will depend on how many symmetries of what kind there are, and will probably rely on [burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma) to continue.  If there is any symmetry at all being considered, I doubt it would *only* be $180^\circ$ rotational symmetry.  If you were wanting to solve this via a pen-and-paper approach, it seems like a job for inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: To be clear, all sweets are considered the same and all fruits are considered the same etc... yes?  Also, you speak of a site where you can enter in the result.  What is this site?  Is it a part of an ongoing contest of some sort?  Could you provide a link so we can get more context on the problem?

Comment: I have an answer different than yours and can share what that is and how I got it after you share whatever website it is that you got the problem from.

Comment: I cant share the website cause is with a special login only for member..Anyway i think I have to consider all kind of symetries. I will try and write it here